# WebView video in xaml Does not play correctly

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I open the Binding  url in a web view the video plays just the audio not the visuals on the emulator and my phone.
When I open the Binding url on my pc and phone it works fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="WiscOnline.Mobile.ViewLearningItem"
Title="{Binding LearningItem.Name}">

<WebView x:Name="webView"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Source="{Binding CurrentSource}" />
<StackLayout>
   <Label Text="{Binding LearningItem.ViewUrl}" FontSize="19"></Label>
</StackLayout>
   <WebView Source="{Binding LearningItem.ViewUrl}" ></WebView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: So I think this is my default browser in my phone not working like chrome because when I change the bindedurl to a youtube video i get the same problem.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by adding this to the manifest <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is with Android and it's `WebView` and not specifically with Xamarin. Different versions of Android will support different `WebView` features. Video playback is particularly bad in a `WebView`.

A better option would be to use the native video player for each platform or to at least use the native video player on Android.

You could either use a handy plugin/component for this like [this one](https://components.xamarin.com/view/video-player) (I have not ever tried that one but saw it was recommended by others) or you could try and roll one yourself by using the native Android `VideoView`.

A Xamarin Forms thread about this very issue and using the `VideoView` can be found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18948/xamarin-forms-webview-and-youtube-in-android).